# Merging two Xcode projects

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on Xcode project.
I have two separate projects(the first one in swift and the second in Objective-C) with multiple storyboards.
I want to merge the two projects and merge the storyboards also.
so how can I organize the storyboards and xib files
can someone help me, please !!!!

Comment: To clarify: do you mean to have a new (3rd) project that has contents of both, or you just want to make one of the original two projects a container for the union of the two? (also, I plussed your question b/c it wasn't obvious why this deserved a down vote)

Comment: I want to make one of the original two projects a container for the union of the two @benc

Comment: There might be a lot of integration issues, I suggest this starting point: if there is a big difference in the comparative "size" of the projects (esp. number of files): you should consider moving the contents of the smaller project into the larger project.